# Wrong marker position in Google Maps if 'Accept-Language' is set to a language other than english

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using Google Maps for my website. It displays few markers and fits them all on the screen. Everything works fine if 'Accept-Language' is set to English. As soon as you change 'Accept-Language' on some other language all markers become shuffled on the map. Can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

```
<html>
    <head lang="en">
        <title>GMaps Test</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
        <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            var map;

            // List of markers
            var all_markers = [];

            function map_initialize() {
                var mapOptions = {
                    center: { lat: 57.332332, lng: 34.725238},
                    zoom: 5,
                    zoomControl: true,
                    zoomControlOptions: {
                        style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL
                    },
                    disableDefaultUI: true
                };
                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
                        mapOptions);

                //  Make an array of the LatLng's of the markers to show
                var LatLngList = [
                    {id: "4", pos: new google.maps.LatLng(55,7569492,37,6416684)},

                    {id: "3", pos: new google.maps.LatLng(40,790278,-73,959722)},

                    {id: "7", pos: new google.maps.LatLng(37,8099098,-122,497668)},

                    {id: "1", pos: new google.maps.LatLng(55,7773455,37,6423385)},
                ];

                //  Create a new viewpoint bound
                var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
                // For outputting info
                var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
                //  Go through each...
                for (var i = 0, LtLgLen = LatLngList.length; i < LtLgLen; i++) {

                    // Adding marker to the map
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: new google.maps.LatLng(LatLngList[i].pos.lat(), LatLngList[i].pos.lng()),
                        map: map,
                        icon: "https://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/ms/micons/pink-dot.png"
                    });

                    // Storing marker in a list
                    all_markers.push({id: LatLngList[i].id, marker: marker});

                    // And increase the bounds to take this point
                    bounds.extend(LatLngList[i].pos);

                    // Click handler for the marker
                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
                        return function () {
                            infowindow.setContent('Ololo');
                            infowindow.open(map, marker);
                        }
                    })(marker, i));
                }
                //  Fit these bounds to the map
                if(LatLngList.length > 0) map.fitBounds(bounds);
            };

            google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', map_initialize);
        });

    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="map-canvas" style="height: 100%; width: 100%; padding: 0; margin: 0"></div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: @geocodezip, I've provided complete example. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In javascript the decimal-separator is a point, but you use comma

Comment: @dr-molle, thanks a lot! I knew that it my fault for sure not GMaps's :-)!